# Scale an entire HTML element using CSS, but without children

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to scale entire element to get it scaled (it's a hexagon div) but I don't want it to scale other things inside.

So basically `transform: scale(2);` works fine, but the elements inside are scaled to (for example images and text that is supposed to be inside a div.

Here's some simple example:

```css
.scaled {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class='scaled'>
  <span>non-scaled element</span>
</div>
```

I want element to have normal scale no matter what

Comment: That's what scale does.  You're going to have to wrap the hexagon and place the text contained within to be on the same level so you can scale just the hexagon.

Comment: Your phrase "entire HTML element" makes me think perhaps I'm not understanding you - could you otherwise scale only part of an element. Either way, it sounds like what you want to do is change the width/height of an element instead of scaling it

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you provided no code, it highly depends on what you want to achieve.

But the principle is to scale your hexagon with the value you want, and scale the content with the inverse number of that value.

Here is an example with a scale of 4.

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  transform: scale(4);
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  transform: scale(calc(1/4));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't used CSS in a long time. But isn't there a way to achieve this by using position properties.

Comment: No, because position won't scale your components.

Comment: Ah! Okay. Thanks

Comment: I won't downvote, but it is not an ideal solution for the simple fact that scaling the hexagon shouldn't require you to also scale its contents by an inverse amount.  It is counterintuitive and you won't remember to do both when you have to fix it a year from now.  It would be better to rearrange the html such that the text and content is no longer contained within div hexagon.

Comment: That is why you have Javascript to do that, or even commentaries to find your way back. I'm not saying this is the best solution, I'm saying this is the easiest one, because the hexagon and its content will always be tied by a parent/child relationship, meaning that you won't have to move the content if you move the hexagon (which is even worse than remembering that use the inverse number).